# Pointer-interconvertibility: reinterpret_cast derived to base

Tags: c++, class, pointers, casting

When do a base subobject and a derived object have the same address and it's guaranteed by the Standard? Is the standard-layout class object is only the case? Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct InterfaceB { virtual void b() = 0; };
struct InterfaceD1 : InterfaceB { virtual void d1() = 0; };
struct InterfaceD2 : InterfaceB { virtual void d2() = 0; };
struct Object : InterfaceD1, InterfaceD2
{
    int m;
    virtual void b() override {}
    virtual void d1() override {}
    virtual void d2() override {}
};

int main ()
{ 
    Object ob;
    InterfaceB* ib = static_cast<InterfaceD1*>(&ob);
    InterfaceD1* id1 = &ob;
    InterfaceD2* id2 = &ob;
    std::cout << &ob << " address of Object\n";
    std::cout << ib << " address of InterfaceB\n";
    std::cout << id1 << " address of InterfaceD1\n";
    std::cout << id2 << " address of InterfaceD2\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
012FF838 address of Object
012FF838 address of InterfaceB
012FF838 address of InterfaceD1
012FF83C address of InterfaceD2
```

From this, I could suggest that `reinterpret_cast<InterfaceB*>(ob)` is valid. But what does the Standard say? Class `Object` is not even standard-layout. Can I rely on this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would be undefined behaviour to attempt to use a pointer casted in such a manner.

> [[basic.compound] ¶4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4)
>
> Two objects `a` and `b` are *pointer-interconvertible* if:
>
> [...] one is a **standard-layout class object** and the other is the **first non-static data member** of that object, **or, if the object has no non-static data members, any base class subobject** of that object [...]
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`.

Because `Object` has a non-static data member, it is not valid in standard C++ to `reinterpret_cast` its address to any of its base class subobjects and then use the resulting pointer. Even if `Object` had no non-static data members, it still would not be valid because it is not a standard-layout class.